# C++ Runtime error when linked with Python COM

Tags: python, c++, c, dll

I am currently getting a C++ Runtime error (R6034) when I am using a C DLL to run a python script. [Details of the DLL](https://www.goldsim.com/library/models/featurescapabilities/dllscripts/pythondll/).

I am building the DLL as per instructions provided and have created the required python files so that the DLL module should work. I am getting the mentioned runtime error from my python file, however, and specifically on the following lines:

```
import pythoncom, pywintypes
from win32com.client import Dispatch
```

Does anyone have any advice how to fix this?

I am running Windows 10 with the 32bit version of python installed, in case that helps.

Comment: Ugh, I feel your pain. R6034 indicates that [the DLL has been built without a manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235560(VS.80).aspx). You might try running your code through Dependency Walker, with any luck it will tell you which DLL is the problem.

Comment: I don't understand.  You say you have built a DLL, but you also say that a runtime error occurs when you import an object from win32com.client.  That's a fairly standard 3rd party Python add-on, and would have no connection to your DLL.  Are you sure that's the line of code that triggers the error?

Comment: The dll is used to allow a third-party program to call a python script. If I remove the above imports the error is gone or if I rename/remove msvcr90.dll from the Python27 the error is also gone but the com connection no longer works. Alternatively I can also run the Python script standalone and it works as expected, the only time I get an error is when it is called from the dll.